# Awk printing integer instead of floating point

Tags: floating-point, awk

I want the following awk script to print out the gpa as a floating point number. So the text in the file my_course.txt would look like

```
CSC3320,SYSTEM LEVEL PROGRAMMING,3,1,A
CSC3210,ASSEMBLY LEVEL PROGRAMMING,3,1,B
```

It should check to see if the number in field 4 is 1, if so then multiply field 3 time field 5 by either a 4, 3, or 2 according whether it is A, B, or C. Then add this value to numerator. For the denominator it will just add the value of field 3 to the variable denominator. Then in the END it will divide these two numbers and give an output. However, using the above text it will output 3 for the text above instead of 3.5. I was under the assumption that all number in awk are floating point so whats going on.

```
calculate(){  
  awk -F, '  
  BEGIN{printf "Your GPA is : "}  
  numerator = 0.0;  
  denominator = 0.0;  
  /^CSC/{  
    if($4=1) {  
         if($5=="A"){  
            numerator+=(4.0*$3);  
            denominator+=$3;  
         } else if ($5 == "B"){  
            numerator+=(3.0*$3);  
            denominator+=$3;  
         } else if ($5 == "C"){  
            numerator+=(2.0*$3);  
                denominator+=$3;  
         } else {  
           ;   
        }  
     }  
   }  
   END{print(numerator/denominator)}  
  ' my_course.txt  
}
```

Using

```
END{printf "%g", (numerator/denominator)}
```

prints 3

```
END{printg "%f", (numerator/denominator)}
```

prints 3.000000

Comment: What are the numerator and denominator? (I mean the actual values. I know what the terms mean.)

Comment: The actual values for the file listed above should be numerator = 21 and denominator = 6. For the calculations for numerator = (3*4) + (3*3). For denominator = 3 + 3. However it is printing out 9.000000 for numerator and 3.000000 for denominator.

Comment: I set denominator and numerator equal to zero in the beginning of the script. So every time it ran it lost the previous values and added new ones. Hence the 9.000000 for numerator and 3.000000 for denominator. Because on the last line 3 is value in field 4 and in field 5 the value is B which translates to 3. I feel like an idiot. Thanks for making me actually think to check the values going into the print statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating GPA in awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688488/calculating-gpa-in-awk)

Answer (score 0):

Your script initializes the `numerator` and `denominator` values each time. So second time the result will be `numerator=3*B`, `denominator+=3`. So the result is 3. I assume You would like to sum the values, so the result would be `numerator=3*A+3*B`, `denominator=6`, namely (12+9)/6. On the other hand in the `if` condition You assign a value to `$4` and not checking(!) its value. So it will always be true. Anyway the `if` could be reduced a lot using a hash for the letter-to-value conversion. So a working solution can be:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{printf "Your GPA is : ";V["A"]=4;V["B"]=3;V["C"]=2}
  /^CSC/ && $4==1 && $5~/^[A-C]$/ {numerator+=V[$5]*$3;denominator+=$3}
  END{print numerator/denominator}' <<EOT
CSC3320,SYSTEM LEVEL PROGRAMMING,3,1,A
CSC3210,ASSEMBLY LEVEL PROGRAMMING,3,1,B
EOT
```

Output:

```
Your GPA is : 3.5
```